# How to get more than one datepicker in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

```
   <link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H : %m",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleclick: false,
            displayarea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <asp:Label ID="lblerrormsg" runat="server" Text="Error Message" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<div>
<fieldset class="borrowing">
    <legend>Borrowing</legend>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Loan Date" Font-Bold=true></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="193px" Height="25px"></asp:TextBox>
    <img src="Images/Images/calender.png" />
         <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Loan Date Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Due Date" Font-Bold=true></asp:Label>
    <br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="193px" Height="25px"></asp:TextBox>
    <img src="Images/Images/calender.png" />
      <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Due Date Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
    <br />
```

So this code I'm using is to get datepicker to work on ASP.Net. But the problem is if I want more than one textbox to contain a datepicker in one form it wont work. I've tried coping the code and changing Textbox1 to Textbox2 but no luck. How can I get two datepickers in the same form using this code?

Comment: Instead of finding elements by ID, what about finding the elements by class?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by this? I'm really new to asp.net and this is for a assignment in class. Just want to have two datepickers in one form.

Comment: Assign a class to TextBox1 (by setting the CssClass attribute on the control) and whatever other textbox you want. Then instead of `$("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>")` you'd use `$(".TheClassName")`

Comment: Hey sorry but I cant figure out how to do this. I updated my original post with the rest of the code including the textbox1 and textbox2. Any help would be grealty appericated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a class to the textboxes you want to be datepickers. Then in your jQuery selector, you get the elements by class instead of ID.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="DynDatePicker" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="DynDatePicker" />

$(".DynDatePicker").dynDateTime
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked out. Thank you everyone for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about dynDateTime, but the regular jquery datepicker will work off of any jQuery selector.

So you could put a datepicker on and input with a type=date like this if you are using Html5 datatypes

```
jQuery("input[type=date]")
    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "m.d.yy", changeYear: true, yearRange: "-4:+0" })
    .attr("type", "text");
```

or tag each textbox with a CssClass date and then bind the datepicker like this

```
jQuery("input[type=text].date")
    .datepicker({ dateFormat: "m.d.yy", changeYear: true, yearRange: "-4:+0" })
    .attr("type", "text");
```

And this works on every element in the selector results.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the date picker use a class as the method of selection e.g. class="datepicker" rather than id as id require unique naming but classes can be reused.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H : %m",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleclick: false,
        displayarea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"
    });
});
```

Now assign the class to each text input you wish to display a date picker e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date2" />
```